# Elasticsearch does not start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Elasticsearch 5.0 on my EC2 instance. When I run

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

there is no error, but elasticsearch does not start. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of debugging, there were two issues:

1. I was trying to run Elasticsearch on a t2.small instance. It turns out that for Elasticsearch to run, t2.medium is the minimum configuration you need to have.
2. To see what went wrong when you tried to start elasticsearch, run the following command:

   service elasticsearch status